# Intercepting PrintDialog to XPS Document Writer

Tags: c#, wpf, xps, printdialog

Currently I am providing the user with two controls:  Save and Print.  When the user selects Save, a region of the WPF display is packaged up and sent through a XpsDocumentWriter and the user is prompted and encouraged to sign the new xps document.  When the user selects Print, a PrintDialog.PrintVisual prints that same region to a user selected printer.

All well and good, except that Microsoft XPS Document Writer is one of the choices for printers.  Is there a way to prevent or intercept the user selection of XPS document writer and send them to the Save method so I can prompt the user to sign the xps document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer*: I've never used `PrintDialog` before, but it looks like something like this might work:

```
System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    PrintQueue selectedQueue = printDialog.PrintQueue;
    if (selectedQueue.Name == "Microsoft XPS Document Writer")
    {
        // Run your XPS save & sign code
    }
    else
    {
        // Run your printDialog.PrintVisual() code
    }
}
```

I don't really like having the printer name hard-coded (I assume it varies with language settings).  Possibly there is a better property of [`PrintQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.aspx) that you can use to identify this printer.

Comment: Try selectedQueue.QueueDriver.Name instead - it's the printer driver name, which is also "Microsoft XPS Document Writer". The printer name can (easily) be changed, but from what I've seen the driver name can't be changed (and it's the driver that it's really about after all).