# Printing to PDF is fine, but printing to printer gives blank sheets (XPS Doc in WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing, xps

To preface, my program has a `Frame` with multiple `Pages`. I store pages in a `List<UIElement>`, and use an XPS writer to print them.

```
        private void Print()
        {
            List<UIElement> Pages = new List<UIElement>();

            PrintDialog print = new PrintDialog();
            if (print.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                PageOne one = new PageOne();   // add a few pages for example's sake
                Pages.Add(one);

                PageTwo two = new PageTwo();
                Pages.Add(two);

                var xpsDocWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(print.PrintQueue);
                PrintUIElements(xpsDocWriter, Pages);
            }
       }
```

`PrintUIElements` is what writes to the XPS doc:

```
        private void PrintUIElements(XpsDocumentWriter xpsWriter, List<UIElement> uiElements)
        {
            var fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();

            foreach (UIElement element in uiElements)
            {
                var fixedPage = new FixedPage();
                var pageContent = new PageContent();

                fixedPage.Children.Add(new Frame() { Content = element });
                pageContent.Child = fixedPage;

                fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);
            }

            xpsWriter.Write(fixedDoc);
        }
```

Like I said, printing to PDF via `PrintDialog` works perfectly, but choosing a printer causes it to print blank sheets. Any clues?

Comment: While I didn't solve this issue in particular, I got around it by using `PrintVisual(page)` if the user chooses a printer via `PrintQueue.Name`. If the user selects print to PDF or any other option this approach does not work as it will not paginate the pages and instead request the user to save to a file once per page.  So otherwise it will be done using FixedDocuments. Not a pretty solution but it works.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043761/intercepting-printdialog-to-xps-document-writer/5044929#5044929) answer for more about that.